# Connecting 2 nodes

Tags: go-ethereum

Unable to connect 2 nodes ,it was working fine . When i run the `admin.addPeer("enode info of the 2 node")`
net.peerCount turns 1 for some time and returns 0 again .
Any idea whats going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Give more details about your setup such as:

- how are you launching the **geth** instances?
- are you using the same block chain (genesis block and network id) for both?
- are you running the private test net locally?
- if yes, only one can use the default port (30303). How are you launching the second instance of **geth**?
- are you using an IPv4 address such as 0.0.0.0? If yes change it to the loop back address (127.0.0.1) but not **localhost**. The same goes if it's an external address (do not use a domain name).
- what does the **geth** console say when you add the peer?